# How to integrate custom module in Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I have created a custom module in Magento 1.9. I want to move this custom module in Magento 2.

I read few articles and also the Magento 2 custom module creation, but I am getting confused from where to start. How to integrate custom code in Magento 2. I have read Magento 2 article that how to create a custom module in Magento 2 but still, I am confused !!

Comment: It would be great if you asked specific questions because it depends what you want to do. You always start with folder structure, sample skeleton: `https://github.com/AOEpeople/Magento-2-Module-Skeleton/tree/master/src`. Then add Models, Observers, Controllers etc.

Comment: above github link is not working

Comment: Sorry, try [this one](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Magento-2-Module-Skeleton/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference in the file structure of Magento 1 and Magento 2. In Magento 1 you have to create your module in app/code/local whereas in Magento 2 you have to create module in app/code.

Check out the method to create a simple module in Magento 2:

Fisrt, go to app from root directory of Magen*emphasized text*to 2 and create new directory **code**.

Then create two more directories in app/code, Namespace and Module Name. The final directory will look like this: app/code/Demo/Mymdoule.

**Demo** as **Namespace** and **Mymodule** as **module name**.

Configure module by creating config.xml file in app/code/Demo/Mymodule/etc and past this code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Demo_Mymodule" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

Register your module be creating registration.php in app/code/Demo/Mymodule and paste this code into the file:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Demo_Mymodule',
__DIR__
);
```

Then run these commands in the root directory:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Demo_Mymodule
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Run the following command and you will see your module in the enabled list which means your module is created successfully:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```